# Atribuir tipo para parâmetros

Tags: php, parâmetros, tipagem

É possível atribuir tipos para os parâmetros em funções no PHP?

Exemplo:

```
public function random(int $length) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É possível parcialmente através do chamado [*type hinting*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). Só pode usar tipos complexos, como objetos, *arrays* ou tipos chamáveis (*lambdas*). Não é possível usar tipos escalares como é o caso do `int` ou `string` o que perde muito da vantagem.

Ainda assim o suporte dado pelo compilador é limitado. Lembre-se que a linguagem é dinâmica e nem sempre é possível garantir tudo o que se deseja sem perda de flexibilidade.

Há [informações que o PHP 7 teria](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints) isso ampliado (de fato aconteceu, especialmente em 7.4), afinal [Hack](http://hacklang.org/), que é uma nova concorrente, permite o chamado *type specification* de forma bastante ampla (muda o nome em PHP também).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ou o `SplType`, como respondi :)

Comment: Para complementar: O PHP 7 já aceita http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Answer (score 9):

No PHP 5 abriu-se a possibilidade de defenir o tipo (*Type*) dos argumentos da função, mas só para objetos/classes.

Seguindo [a documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> Type Hints can only be of the object and array (since PHP 5.1) type. Traditional type hinting with int and string isn't supported.

Tradução livre:

> Sugesões de *Type* do podem ser do tipo *objeto* e *array* desde a versão 5.1. Sugestões de tipo mais tradicionais como *int* ou *string* não são suportados.

Esta possibilidade já é discutida [hà bastante tempo](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2009/07/07/php-type-hinting/) mas ainda não foi implementada.

Answer (score 3):

Com citado pelo @Maniero, não é possível atribuir a indução de tipo para uma função ou método quando se trata de valores escalares.

Creio que a única forma no PHP de forçar parâmetros do tipo `scalar` no PHP seria apenas da biblioteca `Spl Type`.

Assim você poderia fazer algo como

```
function soma(SplInt $a, SplInt $b) {
    return $a + $b;
}
```

Aí ficaríamos limitados à seguinte declaração:

```
soma(new SplInt(3), new SplInt(5));
```

Não creio que seja vantajoso fazer tal coisa, mas essa é uma resposta apenas à nível de informação.

## Atualização

O que foi citado acima refere-se apenas a versões anteriores ao PHP 5.6. Para as versões iguais ou superiores ao PHP 7.0, é possível definir o tipo do parâmetro e retorno esperado pela função.