# O que seria um chamado de parâmetros antes da string em uma função

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, funções, tipagem

Eu já vi várias vezes fazerem isso:

```
interface LoggerAwareInterface
{
     public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger);
}
```

Colocarem um parâmetro antes da variável, no caso o que seria e o que isto faz?

Comment: [Atribuir tipo para parâmetros](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53475/91) e [O que a aplicação ganha utilizando Type Hint?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82465/91)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isto não é parâmetro, o parâmetro é o `$logger`. O que vem antes, o `LoggerInterface`, é o tipo do parâmetro. Ou seja, [o PHP só aceitará uma chamada a este método se for passado um argumento deste tipo de dado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107705/101). Assim o método passa ter uma [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) que é fundamental em interfaces.

Parece um pouco estranho em PHP porque é uma linguagem de [tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101), mas é comum em outras linguagens e para algumas tarefas no PHP isto é útil para deixar o código mais robusto. Pela sua característica dinâmica, a robustez só se dará com testes, já que em vez de pegar em compilação o erro só será descoberto em tempo de execução lançando uma exceção.

Um tipo pode ser definido por classes, ou interfaces, como no exemplo, ou *traits* além de ter os tipos "primitivos" (escalares) que nas versões antigas do PHP não poderiam ser usados como *type hinting* de parâmetros. Na versão 7 isto se transformou em [*type declaration*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) e pode ser usado em qualquer função.

Como é PHP tem uma série de cuidados para usar isso de forma eficaz, então uma lida na documentação é fundamental.

Comment: No caso uma classe?

Comment: Um tipo pode ser definido por uma classe.

Answer (score 5):

Esse recurso se chama *Type Hinting*.

Ele serve para determinar que um parâmetro precisa ter um determinado tipo. Antes do PHP 7, não eram suportados tipos escalares( *int*, *float*, *bool* e *string* ). No exemplo que você mostrou, o parâmetro `$logger` deve ter o tipo `LoggerInterface`. Se ele não tiver, uma exceção é lançada.

O *Type Hinting* é muito usado, principalmente pelos *Frameworks*, porque ele permite assegurar que, se os "contratos" definidos pela assinatura de um método não são cumpridos, uma exceção vai ser lançada. Isso ficou mais completo com o lançamento do PHP 7, com o suporte à tipos escalares.

Para ler mais sobre *Type Hinting*: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.typehinting.php