# passando classe e variável no contruct

Tags: php

```
<?php
   private $pessoa;

   public function __construct(Pessoa $pessoa) {
     $this->pessoa = $pessoa;
   }
```

Como assim no contruct passa a classe `Pessoa`e uma variável???...como essa variável no construct vai receber a classe `Pessoa`??

Estou me referindo ao padrão **Adapter**

Comment: [Atribuir tipo para parâmetros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53475/91)

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade ele esta recebendo uma variável do tipo Pessoa. Como o construtor esta pedindo um objeto do tio `Pessoa` como parâmetro, caso quem for usar a classe passe qualquer outra coisa como parâmetro, receberá um erro automaticamente.

A partir da versão 7 do `PHP` você pode ou não colocar tipos nas suas variáveis.

Por exemplo, se você quiser fazer uma função que obrigatoriamente retorne um `int`, pode fazer assim:

```
public function getId(): int{
    return 0;
}
```

e se você quiser receber um parâmetro que obrigatoriamente tem que ser `int`, você faria assim:

```
public function setId(int $id){
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

Caso você precise que seu parâmetro seja do tipo `int` e que também possa receber `null`, você pode colocar um sinal de interrogação antes do tipo:

```
public function setId(?int $id){
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que deve está havendo uma confusão de entendimento.
O padrão acima tem conceitos de orientação a objeto. uma variável do tipo objeto irá receber os atributos da class Pessoa.
exemplo a classe Pessoa possui seguintes atributos:

```
 public class Pessoa
    {
       public string nome { get; set; }
        public int idade { get; set; }
        public char sexo { get; set; }
    }
```

daí podemos criar uma variavel que irá armazenar esse objeto com todos o as atributos

Variável "pessoa" do tipo "Pessoa" recebe null e depois é preenchida .

```
Pessoa pessoa = null;
       try
        {
             pessoa = new Pessoa ();     //'cria uma instância para Pessoa'
                    pessoa.nome = "Danielle";
                    pessoa.sexo ="F";
                    pessoa.idade= 30;
                    dados.Add(pessoa);
          }
```

Esse conceito é usado para programação Orientada a objeto. Independe da linguagem. Espero Ter ajudado

Comment: Espero ter ajudado no seu entendimento. Como eu disse, o conceito de Orientação Objeto é o mesmo a todas as linguagens.